# "Coupling" gain-setting resistors in a single-ended source, differential amplifier?

Tags: differential, gain, coupling

I am working on a fully differential amplifier design that receives a single-ended differential voltage from a piezo sensor.

I computed a theoretical gain and selected appropriate resistors and it works. However, I want to be able to fine-adjust the gain. Obviously this is difficult when the resistor values must *exactly* match.

Is there a way I can couple the two feedback resistors (if selected to be matching) in a differential setup to both be "divided" by a common value set via trim pot?

[image]

Comment: Use an instrumentation amplifier (in-amp) which has a single gain setting resistor. Or, take the output from a tap on R5.

Comment: You've asked 11 questions now and got some good answers but it seems you are possibly not aware of the etiquette in these parts so, now seems like a good time to learn. If you receive good answers you should consider up-voting them even if there is a better answer. For the best answer (and one that delivers what you need to know) you should formally accept it by [pressing this symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png). It's all optional but, I guarantee you'll get better responses if you "play the game".